# When using "long" meaning "a long time" do you have to specify that you're talking about time?

Tags: word-choice

For example: Do I have to say "It leaves the mouth fresher for a longer time" or can I simply say "It leaves the mouth fresher for longer"?
I was comparing two products, and I had to translate some comments about them into English.

Comment: Yes, you can say "leaves your mouth fresher for longer".

Comment: Is it grammatically incorrect to say "for long"? For example: "It leaves your mouth fresh for long"

Comment: While one might argue that "It leaves your mouth fresh for long" is grammatical, no native English speaker would talk that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to state it in a way that sounds natural, ie the way a native English speaker would say it, you'd say either

> leaves your mouth fresher for longer

or even briefer,

> leaves your mouth fresher longer

In fact, the *for long* in your comment example is more often used in the negative:

> your mouth will be fresh, but not for long

meaning the sensation won't last.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't ordinarily have to specify that you're talking about time.  If someone talks about yeast going a long way, it's understood that "a little leaven leaveneth the whole lump." If you're talking about your tires going a long way, it's understood that the tread lasts many miles.  If your chewing gum goes a long way, it's understood that it loses its flavor on the bed post overnight, not in your mouth.  *Only when you refer to longevity in an unusual measure do you need to specify the reference.*

There was an advertiser perhaps 35 tears ago that said their product "keeps you fresher longer"  Ad agencies have no reluctance to mangle the language on order to make a lasting impression, and obviously I still remember the phrase (but not the product!), but because it was an unusual construction, not because it was a sin against grammar.